# Why is my apricot seedling turning brown?

Tags: fruit-trees, leaves, germination, seedlings, apricots

My first apricot seedling has leaves, but they are turning somewhat brown. I can't find any information about this, so maybe someone knows?

- Could it be too humid? It lives in a little plastic greenhouse box.
- Could it be too hot? It's in direct sunlight for about 5 hours in the mornings.

They seem to be sprouting very easily, so it seems the conditions are at least somewhat okay.

Here is a picture:

[image: Apricot seedling]

Today I put it in indirect light, and took the plastic cover off so there is good ventilation, but I have literally zero idea what's happening. It may be too late for this little guy (or maybe not?), but there are a bunch more who just got their roots and I want those to live!

Edit: another picture. This seedling is quite small, so I can't get a more zoomed in picture. The browning is pretty obvious though.

[image: Another view of browning]

Comment: I don't see the brown leaves.  Can you post a close up picture as well?  The original leaves will turn brown so if that is the issue, you are okay

Comment: @JStorage, I added another picture. That's the most close up one I can get, but the browning is pretty evident I think. I don't think this is a matter of just original leaves turning brown. The leaves didn't even grow to any decent size before going brown (and quite limp as it turns out).

Comment: Catsunami...please tell us how you are watering (these little seeding pots are super) but with the cover there should be no watering. When the cover is on it should be either under artificial lights held very high above.  Are you using tap water from the city?  Most importantly did you fertilize?  Plant starts should not be given any fertilizer until at least 3 or 4 leaf sets, sometimes even longer. To set them in direct sun with the cover on it will get VERY hot!  If so, as you suspected, these plants got far too hot!  The browning is obvious and looks like overly cooked plant material.

Comment: But they should still be able to thrive if you stop the direct sunlight with the cover on.  Less direct sunlight WITHOUT the cover, and more in bright shade until they get big enough to transplant.  When you do transplant go to a 3 or 4" pot no larger, potting soil, light fertilizer,allow to dry before lightly watering again AND TAKE THE FABRIC off the start before planting!  I've used these before but you have to peel that mesh off before transplanting.

Comment: @stormy, thanks for your response! I haven't watered since I planted them, so I don't know, I have no routine for these guys yet. I normally water my other plants when they get dry. I did not fertilize them. Alright, I'll keep them out of direct sun until they get a bit bigger. Thanks again!

Comment: Pretty sure they got a bit cooked but they should still do fine.  Have you ever had a fish tank left in the sun?  Cooked fish.  I am glad you wait to water until the soil gets dryish.  Great practice!  The best place to get the best plant stuff are the Cannabis shops.  Kid you not.  Find a proper organic fertilizer like 5-5-5 or similar equal percentages yet low (versus 14-14-14).  Be very stingy with fertilizer.  I wouldn't fertilize until that seed is quite diminished.  Forget about any routine!  That is a good thing as plants do not like routines as do animals!

Comment: @stormy, can't say I ever have left fish in the sun :) Not sure what my thought process behind leaving them in the sun was exactly. It was cold for a while so I guess I figured it would keep them warm. Anyway, the new leaves seem alright for now (I moved it yesterday). More seeds are coming up, so hopefully they turn out okay. I'll keep an eye out for the proper fertilizer! It'll be a while until I fertilize them though.

Comment: I am glad that my answer hit home.  It is so difficult to figure out what to say that would help so shoot, I always go on and on.  You'll be able to tell when they need a bit of fertilizer, the leaves will be too light of a green (once you've got real leaves).  Just transplant them into slightly larger pots each transplanting using potting soil.  Are you planning to plant outside someday?  Of course you are unless you've got a greenhouse available.  Make sure you 'harden' them off but you've got awhile before you need to worry about planting them in the garden.  We'll be here to help!

Comment: @stormy, wow thanks for the extra advice! Actually your comment about the leaves being too light probably means my avocados need fertilizer. I will do that tonight! I am going to keep the apricots in the greenhouse as long as I can. I might potentially give them to a friend who lives in a better climate. We'll just have to see! I am happy to say, though, that the little seedling in this post has put out new leaves and they look normal :)

Comment: Excellent!!  I think you should have an atrium or greenhouse.  Sounds like you are a major gardener, like 'gifted' and love plants, watching them grow and change.  Keep us updated will you?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like too much sun - some damaged tissue but it shouldn't be fatal. Usually you need to harden plants off when moving them to different lighting (especially newly germinated plants). Also, the seedlings will outgrow those pots in no time. Be ready with bigger pots (or a spot in the ground if the weather's right).

On another note, watch that the soil isn't saturated. Saturated soil can germinate a tree seed, which can push a root, and then not take, and end up withering and dying after what looked like success.